# How to draw and update a shape given an array of coordinates captured over a 15 second interval (SWIFT UI)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

(New to Swift) I have an array of x coordinates of a single object over the course of 15 seconds that I have extracted from a video. I would like iterate over those points, draw the current point, then refresh the view and draw the next coordinate point in the array, replacing the previous. I am also playing a video concurrently underneath the drawing using swift ui's VideoPlayer.

I have a shape struct as so:

```
struct Stick: Shape {
var points: [CGPoint]
var size: CGSize
func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var path = Path()
    path.move(to: points[0])
    for point in points {
        path.addLine(to: point)
    }
    return path.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height))
        .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -size.width, y: -size.height))
}

}
```

To iterate through the points in each array, I created a class that conforms to the Observable Object protocol.

```
class Points : ObservableObject{
var pointArr = [0.1981825828552246, 0.3635875880718231, 0.363417387008667, 0.36394527554512024, 0.3631347119808197, 0.3628629148006439, 0.36222490668296814]
@Published var point = 0.0

    
    
func updatePoint(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        for p in self.pointArr{
            self.point = p
            print(self.point)
        }
    }

}
}
```

I then have this code where I use a button click to call updatePoint() and begin iterating through the coordinate array.

```
struct VideoView: View {
@ObservedObject var updatePoints :  Points

var body: some View {


ZStack{
    Button("Press"){
        updatePoints.updatePoint()
    }
    //I just used random fixed points for the other coordinates
    Stick(points: [CGPoint(x: updatePoints.point, y: 1.0), CGPoint(x:0.36, y:0.0)], size: CGSize(width: 414, height: 814))
        .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
            .fill(Color.green)

}
}
}
```

My thought process behind this code is that because the Points class conforms to observable object protocol, every time the point variable is reassigned in the for-loop, the VideoView will be redrawn passing in the new point value into the Stick struct. However, the VideoView is only redrawn once after the for-loop has completed, passing in the very last coordinate in the array to the Stick struct. I assume this has something to do with the for loop being in the main thread and the view not updating until the for loop has completed.

This is what i'm after in pseudocode:

```
for point in videoPoints{
    Stick(point)        //draw that point
}
```

This problem has had me stumped for a couple of days now so any help is much appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: The code doesn't compile, mainly the `pointArr`. Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: @George I think I fixed it, try it now!

Comment: I don't think the issue is that the video is only being redrawn for the last point. I think it is being redrawn each time and you can't see it until the last point. So, instead of a bunch of your `Sticks`, you are only seeing the last. It would seem to me that you would want to pass the entire array at once to your view, and then iterate over it in the body with a ForEach. That would draw multiple `Sticks` in one view draw.

Comment: @Yrb Thank you very much for the suggestion! However, when I use a ForEach loop it just overlays each 'Sticks' on top of each other. I want to only show one 'Sticks' at a time.

Comment: How do you want to determine when the next `Stick` is shown? I still think it should be handled in the UI, not the Model.

Comment: @Yrb I want to iterate through the array of x coordinates and draw a Stick that represents the current value in the array. In other words, while iterating over the array, I only want a Stick of the current item in the array to be drawn. Hope this clarifies!

Comment: I think you are doing that, but at such a high rate of speed(milliseconds), it isn't displaying. You need to time out the display of your `Sticks`. I would consider using an animation series to do this.

Comment: @Yrb could you explain what an animation series is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Combine framework to publish these values over time.

In the `Points` class, add the following (replacing `updatePoint()`):

```
private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

func updatePoint() {
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.2, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()

    Publishers.Zip(pointArr.publisher, timer)
        .sink { (p, _) in
            self.point = p
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61212823/9607863) answer on how delaying the values work with `Timer`. Basically, `Zip` only emits a value when both `pointArr.publisher` and `timer` emit a value. The `pointArr` is instant, so the `timer` is there to keep the pace.

You can set the delay as whatever you want, currently it is `0.2` seconds. Although it looks like the line might instantly go to the last point, it's because your sample points are very close together after the first one. Try another point like `0.5` and you will see it still moves with delay between.